# finnding the shortest path between two given points (an origin and a destination)

Tags: algorithms, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

How Mathematically to find the closest distance rect between 2 points Summing the distances in x and y

Example

For departure = [0.4, 1] and destination = [0.9, 3], the output should be
perfectCity(departure, destination) = 2.7.

0.6 + 2 + 0.1 = 2.7, which is the answer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PthPO.png

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdW21.png

sorry for my English..

Comment: Do the towns need to have the y coordinate integer, or just one of the two?

Comment: just one of the two http://i.imgur.com/BtPfEQG.png

Comment: When two coordinates share the dame integer part the best that you can do is to evaluate both distances and find the minimum.